# Vendor for geospecial lat/long polygons for google maps

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am looking for a vendor which sells geospacial data for polygons. Business requirement is to map polygons based on dynamic report. This report can return country, state, zip, county. So I need arrays of latitudes/longitudes for all those. Does anyone know of vendors which supply this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) TomTom (previously called TeleAtlas)
2) Nokia (previously called Navteq)

3) for free: Openstreetmap: The company "Geofabric" converts them to other formats, and makes them clean (non segmented)

point 1 and 2 is only for major projects with a big budget.

The "zip" can be more difficult. You would need special data, which are not standard.

You also might consider using a "paid" web service which does the geo coding for you.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This project has funding so open source is not a necessity. I would like to host all of my data in house so I can pregenerate all of the google javascript necessary to render any given polygon. I actually already have all of the zip code data for the united states so I really only need other areas